# Could nginx mail module replace a Postfix/Dovecot combo

Tags: nginx, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I saw that nginx has a "[Mail Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_core_module.html)". I googled but don't find much documentation about this.

What is this ? For what can it be used ?
Could it replace my current simple Postfix/Dovecot combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this? For what can it be used?

It's IMAP/POP3/SMTP proxy. It is used as a bridge between outside connection and interal mail server. It's often placed when you only have one IP address and mail server was separated with nginx server.

> Could it replace my current simple Postfix/Dovecot combo?

## No

Nginx mail module doesn't have postfix  rich features like multiple restrictions and basic spam prevention. It also can't handles email storage and email indexing like dovecot features.